# Привести BooleanPath в StringPath в QueryDsl

Tags: java

Есть такой код:

```
private List<String> stateList;

private void createStatePredicateNotExists(BooleanBuilder predicate) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(stateList)) {
      predicate.andNot(orderEntity.status.in(stateList));
    }
  }
```

`orderEntity.status` имеет тип `BooleanPath`, поэтому код не компилируется в кейсе `in`. Как привести `orderEntity.status` из `BooleanPath` в `StringPath`, чтобы код компилировался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще можно воспользоваться приведением типа [BooleanPath](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/BooleanPath.html) к [StringExpression](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/StringExpression.html) при помощи метода [stringValue](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/LiteralExpression.html#stringValue--).

Однако, тут стоит скорее задаться другим вопросом: "Почему `stateList` имеет тип `List<String>`, а не `List<Boolean>`?" Возможно стоит изменить тип для `stateList`.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Разобрался еще вчера, но ответить на свой вопрос смогу только завтра) к сожалению, такая логика, поэтому менять тип не могу.